# Enabling https on server for one site but not another

Tags: https

I have run into an issue when enabling https on a server that hosts many sites.  I have only enabled https for one site (site1.com), but when a user tries to browse to site2.com which doesn't have https enabled, if they try to get to https://www.site2.com, it redirects to https://www.site1.com.  Can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

You will need two IPs for that and host one site with a different IP.

The 'problem' is that SSL connection is established on IP basis through TCP before the HTTP Server gets the Request, which is then already encrypted. Since your SSL port is linked to site1 this site will be served.

If your DNS A-Records point to the same IP then the only way i see you could do this is either use two IPs or enter the URL of site2 with http://site2.com (explicitly without HTTPS). In that case the connection would be opened unencrypted on Port 80.

Setup two IPs use HTTPS for one and not the other.

Comment: I am not a networking person, how would I go about changing a site's IP address?

Comment: Please describe your setup in more detail. Is it a local setup in your intranet or something public? What kind of webserver are you running (Apache, IIS)?

In principle you just need to add an IP address to your server in your operating system. Then configure the Webserver to run on that IP as well. But... if you're running a publicly available server you can't just add any IP address. Your hoster / provider needs to assign them to you.